# How to put 3 pictures in a horizontal row evenly spaced apart

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have 3 pictures in a horizontal row but I want them to be evenly spaced out and at the moment, they seem squished together leaving room on the far right side. I'm new to LaTeX so please bear with me! I assume it's something to do with `{.3\textwidth}` but when I play around with this, it changes their sizes and puts them on new lines.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[angle=270, width=1\linewidth]{Trisecting an angle 1}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[angle=270, width=1\linewidth]{Trisecting an angle 2}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include third image
  \includegraphics[angle=270, width=1\linewidth]{Trisecting an angle 3}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Put your caption here}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In figure below images are pushed away with ˙|hfill` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht] 
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth} 
\centering 
% include first image 
\includegraphics[angle=270, width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}%{Trisecting an angle 1}   
\caption{Put your sub-caption here} 
\label{fig:sub-first} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill% <---
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth} 
\centering 
% include second image 
\includegraphics[angle=270, width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}%{Trisecting an angle 2}   
\caption{Put your sub-caption here} \label{fig:sub-second} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill% <--- 
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth} 
\centering 
% include third image 
\includegraphics[angle=270, width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}%{Trisecting an angle 3}   \caption{Put your sub-caption here} \label{fig:sub-second} 
\end{subfigure} 
\caption{Put your caption here} 
\label{fig:fig} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)